# Problema al codificar en base 64 una imagen enviada y devuelta por ajax con jquery

Tags: php, ajax, base64

estoy intentado realizar un pequeño programa para previsualizar una imagen capturada por el movil (y con meta información IMEX: http://www.cellutips.com/exif-data-is-your-friend/) en un formulario html. 
Utilizo el Ajax para procesar en el servidor la imagen capturada y devolverla al usuario/a para que la visualice correctamente. Aunque las pruebas se pueden realizar con cualquier imagen.

El código php que procesa/orienta la imagen funciona de forma correcta, ya que he probado a grabar la imagen después de ser tratada y el resultado es válido.

Pero al devolver por ajax la imagen, la codificación en base 64 no es correcta y no puedo ver la imagen procesada.

Por favor, podrían revisar el código y ofrecer alguna alternativa. Prque no tengo manera de que funcione.

Adjunto imágenes de prueba y la imagen con la información devuelta en el formulario html.

El código que utilizo es:

```
index.html
----------

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function($) {

})(jQuery);

jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
});

function previewImage(){
    fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $("#img")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/pruebas/jquery01/analyze.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#photoPreview").html(result);
        }});

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form >
  <label for="img">Select image:</label>
  <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage()" >

</form>
<div id='photoPreview' style="border:solid 1px; width:5rem; height:10rem">

</div>
</body>

</html>

analyze.php
-----------
<?php
        if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
                $exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
                        $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
                        if($orientation != 1){
                                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                $deg = 0;
                                switch ($orientation) {
                                        case 3:
                                                $deg = 180;
                                                break;
                                        case 6:
                                                $deg = 270;
                                                break;
                                        case 8:
                                                $deg = 90;
                                                break;
                                }
                                if ($deg) {
                                        $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);
                                }
                                // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename
                                imagejpeg($img, $_FILES['fotoPersonal']['tmp_name'], 95);
                        } // if there is some rotation necessary
                        else{
                                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                imagejpeg($img, null, 95);
                        }
                } // if have the exif orientation info
                else{
                    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                    imagejpeg($img, null, 95);
                }
        } // if function exists

        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($img);
        $outputBuffer = ob_get_clean();
        $base64 = base64_encode($outputBuffer);
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64.'" />';
        ob_end_clean();
?>

'''


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXIaI.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtUMg.jpg
```

Comment: Buenas, si lo que quieres es desencriptar el base64 usa decode no encode.

Comment: Hola, y gracias por tu interés, es encode porque el resultado viajará como respuesta a la petición AJAX. DE todas formas he probado y el resultado es similar.  Ver la imagen de la siguiete url: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtUMg.jpg

Comment: He revisado mucho la petición ajax por si el problema es por esa parte, pero no encuentro la solución de momento.

Comment: Buenas, casi al final del todo, tienes un encode (lo trasformas a base64) y la variable la pones en la "img", por tanto, estás poniendo un valor en base64 a la img. Prueba a usar atog y bta -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_codificando_y_decodificando

Comment: Hola, he probado ese ajuste también, antes de subir la pregunta y ahora al tu proponérmelo,  y no resuelve el caso. En el siguiente enlace se ve una imagen con el error. 
Creo que el origen del error está en como ajax deuelve el mensaje. url:      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m5T7PYziX6XjYFBOAN_JcZG1gB331we1/view

Comment: Por su puesto, gracias por la opciones...Sigo probando y esperando alguna otra opción que me ayude a resolverlo.

Comment: Para comprobar si el base64 que recibes es correcto, usa una web https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Hola, EduBw, he probado la herramienta indicada y no decodifica(DECODE) de forma correcta . El motivo es porque el response de la petición Ajax devuelve una ristra(que corresponde con la información de la imagen) en base64 que no es válida. De hecho se pueden ver muchos triángulos con un signo de interrogación dentro, ver la información recibida en la imagen que puse en el comentario anterior (drive.google.com/file/d/1m5T7PYziX6XjYFBOAN_JcZG1gB331we1/view ). Creo que la incidencia tiene que ver en cómo se realiza la petición AJAX y cómo debe ser la respuesta, pero no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Esta es una imagen donde se puede ver el resultado tras utilizar la herramienta de decode que me has indicado:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J12rUFKRZwix7n6h5vpTBaNwkHquBBcx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sino te están enviando la imagen en base64 poco puedes hacer, levanta una incidencia para que revisen ese servicio, si estuviera en base64 no se leerían cosas como: "CREATOR" y otras cosas...

Comment: Gracias, al final he encontrado el problema y la solución. El origen está en que en el código PHP, para poder hacer el encode_base64 previamente debo guardar la imagen en un fichero físico y después leerla con file_get_content y aplicar el encode_base64. El código PHP que puse en la pregunta incial tenía la intención de devolver la imagen sin tener que crear un fichero físico, pero no me funciona cuando lo quiere combinar con AJAX. Seguramente hay una solución pero de momento lo resuelvo creando un fichero físico temporal, que borro al final del script PHP. Gracias eduBW